# Mysql query group latest insert

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table `tbldevicevaluelog` with the following layout:

```
id | ts | dc | data1 | data2
```

Where `ts` is a timestamp, `dc` is a devicecode. `data1` and `data2` are the latest value.

In total there are 130 different device codes.

The goal is to get the latest time and `data1` from each available device code.

With the query below I can get a result with al the device codes and the latest time.

```
SELECT dc, MAX(ts) FROM tbldevicevaluelog GROUP BY dc
```

The question is how to also get the `data1` which belongs to this latest time?

Comment: try this `select dc, ts from tbldevicevaluelog where ts=max(ts)`

Answer (score 1):

Join your result back to your table on the same device code and timestamp.

```
SELECT tg.dc, tg.latest, t.data1 
FROM tbldevicevaluelog t
JOIN
( SELECT dc, MAX(ts) as latest FROM tbldevicevaluelog GROUP BY dc ) tg
ON tg.dc=t.dc AND tg.latest=t.ts
```